# Keeping a div box intact just like gmail

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I have a webpage with few links already made.

Now I want that a divbox should appear (just like when we compose message in gmail a divbox appears).
When it appears, I will click on the link available at the webpage (which i mentioned in the very first line), now it will take me to another webpage, but I don't want the divbox to disappear, it should remain where it was. How can I do this?

The divbox should not refresh itself , only the page should get refreshed once I click on the link.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I don't understand the question even - what the hell is a 'divbox'?

Comment: At least give us something you have made.

Comment: When clicking the link, replace the content of current page using `AJAX`.

Comment: to clarify: you want a POPUP to remain in place while the page behind it reloads?

Comment: yes webkit, that, I just want a very basic and simple demo (which is easy to understand) so that I can know how exactly it can be done... I am sorry i am not that of a coder, so apologies to those who didn't understand. Divbox means, a div tag with display as block and with borders.